# Is there an non provable sentence from Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: prime-numbers, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I'm trying to deduce the following sentence using only Peano Axioms:

"There exist infinite prime numbers"

Since PA is known to be incomplete, its possible there is no such proof supporting the sentence from PA's axioms.

How can I tell if the sentence is indeed unprovable?

Comment: The first thing to do is to write down this sentence in the language of Pean Axioms. I would write "for all primes $p$ there exists a larger prime $q$", whose proof is Euclid's classical proof.

Comment: To formalize the claim within Peano, you need to replace the common-english with a very formal and boring first-order sentence. But it is provable, you can translate all of Euclid's proof in Peano.

Comment: (But it is a well-known result that there indeed are many other sentences that are neither provable nor refutable.)

Comment: OK, can you provide one sentence, except of G (Godel sentence), which isn't consequence of PA axioms?

Comment: @Yan: See, for example, [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem).

Comment: Assuming PA is consistent (a reasonable belief), there **are** sentences unprovable in PA. But this is not one of them.

Comment: Even if a proof for a sentence is known, it might be difficult to decide whether it can be proven in PA. For example : Can Fermat's last theorem be proven in PA ? In the case of Euclid's proof, I am convinced that it can be translated in PA, but I admit that I could not prove that it is actually the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of [Euclid's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) asserting that there are infinitely many prime numbers is proved from first-order [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) into :

- S.C.Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=O28-AQAAIAAJ) (1952) , *161, page 191-92.

Here is a sketch of the proof.

*Definitions* [page 191]:

i) $a|b$ [read $a$ divides $b$] is an abbreviation for : $\exists c \ (a \times c = b)$.

ii) $Pr(a)$ [read "$a$ is prime"] is : $a > 1 \land \lnot \exists c \ ( 1 < c < a \land c|a)$.

Using them, Euclid's theorem is :

> $\exists b \ (Pr(b) \land b > a)$ ["for any number $a$, there is a prime greater than $a$"].

The result needs a preliminary Lemma [page 192]:

> *157. $\exists d \ [d > 0 \land \forall b \ (0 < b \le a) \to b|d)]$ (Existence of common multiples of $1, \ldots, a$.)

The proof of the Lemma is by induction on $a$ : it is needed because in the system there is no term to express the function $a!$.